# When did the original names of the months change?

Tags: history, names, calendar, months

The Haftorah this past week mentions the second month using the name Ziv. The orignal names of the months are discussed here: [First-Temple-Era names of the Hebrew months?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14830/first-temple-era-names-of-the-hebrew-months)  When did the original names of the months change?

Comment: Presumably around the exile to Babylon. Do you need a more specific 'moment' in time?

Comment: @Double AA  Are all the Hebrew names of the months Babylonian in origin? (A general time period satistfies my curiosity.)

Comment: The names "Bul", "Ethanim", and "Ziw" are Phoenician names and occur only in the narrative of the construction of Solomon's Temple.  This was a Phoenician-style temple designed by a Phoenician architect, and the writer's use of these names may reflect his use of Phoenician source documents.  They are not Israelite names.  The Israelite practice seems to have been to number the months.  The names "Bul" and "Ethanim" are attested in extra-biblical sources, while "Ziw" so far is not.

Answer (score 4):

The names of the months came up with them from Bavel. Talmud Yerushalmi Rosh Hashana perek one, halacha two. This Yerushalmi is mentioned in Tosafos Rosh Hashana 7a, d.h. Midivrei.

Most of the names are mentioned in megilas Esther and Nechemia.

We can estimate then, at least to the latest possible date, based on Achashveirosh's reign. Wiki states Ahasuerus is usually identified as Xerxes I (486–465 BCE).