# Where in tanach are the months named

Tags: names, tanach, calendar, months

In megilas esther the months of the year are called out by name. For example the 12th month is called adar. Is there anywhere else in tanach that months are referred to by name?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14830

Comment: All over the place. Just maybe not with the names you are familiar with.

Comment: Follow up on @DoubleAA's comment and to verify. Are you seeking only the Baylonian names we use today or some of the other names that were used in Tanac"h, as well. There are a few mentioned, particularly, in Sefer Melachim (Kings) that are no longer used, today.

Comment: @DanF The OP specifically mentioned Adar. I understood that to mean that Babylonian names were desired. (*Double AA is definitely right that the post may be slightly less than perfectly accurate, but I think we all know what is meant here*)

Answer (score 8):

Just searching around in Torat Emet finds a few mentions of different months, in Tanach, besides for Adar:

#### Nissan

[Esther 3:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16476#v=7)

[Nechemiah 2:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16509#v=1)

#### Sivan

[Esther 8:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16481#v=9)

#### Tammuz

[Yechezkel 8:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16106#v=14) (kidding)

#### Elul

[Nechemiah 6:15](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16513#v=15)

#### Kislev

[Nechemiah 1:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16508#v=1)

[Zechariah 7:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16211#v=1)

#### Teves

[Esther 2:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16475#v=16)

#### Shevat

[Zechariah 1:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16205#v=7)

*NB: This list may be incomplete.*

Comment: This answer could not have been written so quickly were it not for [Hod's referencer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1758/5323) -- thanks! :-D

Comment: In the Gemara in Rosh Hashanah (7a-ish) many of these pesukim are brought as proofs that Nissan is the first month of the year.

Comment: Also, Ester 3:7, 3:13, 8:12, and 9:1 all reference Adar as being the 12th month.